# Datatable -altEditor and select2

Tags: datatables, jquery-select2

For adding, deleting and changing data I use DataTable-AltEditor

modelOption and groupOption loaded sucessfull.
render to field Model and Group work good. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiRKL.png)

But when I call Edit or Add, can select or change Model is fulfilled, but Group is empty and doesn't have any data. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ztHU.png)

Any idea?

code below

devicesTable.js

```
let modelOptions;
let groupOptions;
$(document).ready(function () {


    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: getContextPath() + '/front/api/printers/getmodels',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            modelOptions = json;
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("Can't load models.");
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: getContextPath() + '/front/api/printers/getgroups',
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (json) {
            groupOptions = json;
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("Can't load groups\");
        }
    });
    var columnDefs = [

            {
                data: "modelId",
                title: "Model",
                type: "select",
                options: modelOptions,
                select2: {
                    width: "100%",
                },
                render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                    if (data == null || !(data in modelOptions)) return null;
                    return modelOptions[data];
                }
            },

        {
            data: "printerGroupId",
            title: "Group",
            type: "select",
            option: groupOptions,
            select2: {
                width: "100%",
            },
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                if (data == null || !(data in groupOptions)) return null;
                return groupOptions[data];
            }
        },


            {

                data: "printer.name",
                title: "Серийный номер"
            }

        ]
    ;

    var table = $('#usersTable').DataTable(
        {
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            ajax: {
                url: getContextPath() + '/front/api/printers/getprinters',
                dataSrc: ''
            },
            columns: columnDefs,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',        // Needs button container
            select: 'single',
            responsive: true,
            altEditor: true,     // Enable altEditor
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Add',
                name: 'add'        // do not change name
            },
                {
                    extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                    text: 'Change',
                    name: 'edit'        // do not change name
                },
                {
                    extend: 'selected', // Bind to Selected row
                    text: 'Delete',
                    name: 'delete'      // do not change name
                },
                {
                    text: 'Refresh',
                    name: 'refresh'      // do not change name
                }],
```

getprinters.json

```
[{"mppgId":1,"modelId":1,"model":{"id":1,"name":"Q3X-Ф"},"printerId":1,"printer":{"id":1,"name":"0000000000000000007","active":true},"printerGroupId":1,"printerGroup":{"id":1,"name":"Custom#1"}},{"mppgId":2,"modelId":1,"model":{"id":1,"name":"Q3X-Ф"},"printerId":2,"printer":{"id":2,"name":"0000000000000000001","active":true},"printerGroupId":1,"printerGroup":{"id":1,"name":"Custom#1"}},{"mppgId":3,"modelId":1,"model":{"id":1,"name":"Q3X-Ф"},"printerId":3,"printer":{"id":3,"name":"0000000000000000002","active":true},"printerGroupId":1,"printerGroup":{"id":1,"name":"Custom#1"}},{"mppgId":4,"modelId":1,"model":{"id":1,"name":"Q3X-Ф"},"printerId":4,"printer":{"id":4,"name":"0000000000000000003","active":true},"printerGroupId":1,"printerGroup":{"id":1,"name":"Custom#1"}},{"mppgId":5,"modelId":1,"model":{"id":1,"name":"Q3X-Ф"},"printerId":5,"printer":{"id":5,"name":"0000000000000000004","active":true},"printerGroupId":1,"printerGroup":{"id":1,"name":"Custom#1"}},{"mppgId":6,"modelId":1,"model":{"id":1,"name":"Q3X-Ф"},"printerId":6,"printer":{"id":6,"name":"0000000000000000005","active":true},"printerGroupId":1,"printerGroup":{"id":1,"name":"Custom#1"}}]
```

getmodels.json

```
{"1":"Q3X-Ф","6":"VKP-80 RF","7":"TCD"}
```

getgroups.json

```
{"1":"Custom#1","2":"Custom#2","7":"Custom#3","8":"Custom#A","9":"(empty)"}
```

device.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <div class="container">

    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable table table-striped" id="usersTable">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found issue incorrect field `option` (must be `options`)

```
{
            data: "printerGroupId",
            title: "Group",
            type: "select",
            options: groupOptions,
            select2: {
                width: "100%",
            },
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                if (data == null || !(data in groupOptions)) return null;
                return groupOptions[data];
            }
        },
```